# Gradle: More than one variant of project :myLib matches the consumer attributes

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

A library that I wrote `myLib` uses `RemoteMessage` from `Firebase`, the app itself also uses `Firebase`.

Using gradle 4.7. Also facing this in 4.4.1.

How to fix it?

project.gradle

```
buildscript {
    
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.3.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        mavenLocal()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

app.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.test.app"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    dexOptions {
        preDexLibraries = false
        jumboMode = false
        javaMaxHeapSize "2048M"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'

    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:12.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:12.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:12.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:12.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:12.0.1'

    implementation project(":myLib")
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

myLib.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27



    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'

    implementation group: 'com.google.code.gson', name: 'gson', version: '2.8.2'
    implementation 'com.j256.ormlite:ormlite-core:5.0'
    implementation 'com.j256.ormlite:ormlite-android:5.0'

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:12.0.1'
}
```

Error output from `testApp\myLib> gradle clean assembleDebug` and `testApp\app> gradle clean assembleDebug`

> More than one variant of project :myLib matches the
> consumer attributes:
>
> - Configuration ':myLib:debugApiElements' variant android-aidl:
>
>   - Found artifactType 'android-aidl' but wasn't required.
>   - Required com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr 'debug' and found compatible value 'debug'.
>   - Found com.android.build.api.attributes.VariantAttr 'debug' but wasn't required.
>   - Required com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.AndroidTypeAttr 'Aar' and
>     found compatible value 'Aar'.
>   - Required org.gradle.usage 'java-api' and found compatible value 'java-api'.
> - Configuration ':myLib:debugApiElements' variant android-classes:
>
>   - Found artifactType 'android-classes' but wasn't required.
>   - Required com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr 'debug' and found compatible value 'debug'.
>   - Found com.android.build.api.attributes.VariantAttr 'debug' but wasn't required.
>   - Required com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.AndroidTypeAttr 'Aar' and
>     found compatible value 'Aar'.
>   - Required org.gradle.usage 'java-api' and found compatible value 'java-api'.
> - Configuration ':myLib:debugApiElements' variant android-manifest:
>
>   - Found artifactType 'android-manifest' but wasn't required.
>   - Required com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr 'debug' and found compatible value 'debug'.
>   - Found com.android.build.api.attributes.VariantAttr 'debug' but wasn't required.
>   - Required com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.AndroidTypeAttr 'Aar' and
>     found compatible value 'Aar'.
>   - Required org.gradle.usage 'java-api' and found compatible value 'java-api'.
> - Configuration ':myLib:debugApiElements' variant android-renderscript:
>
>   - Found artifactType 'android-renderscript' but wasn't required.
>   - Required com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr 'debug' and found compatible value 'debug'.
>   - Found com.android.build.api.attributes.VariantAttr 'debug' but wasn't required.
>   - Required com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.AndroidTypeAttr 'Aar' and
>     found compatible value 'Aar'.
>   - Required org.gradle.usage 'java-api' and found compatible value 'java-api'.
> - Configuration ':myLib:debugApiElements' variant jar:
>
>   - Found artifactType 'jar' but wasn't required.
>   - Required com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr 'debug' and found compatible value 'debug'.
>   - Found com.android.build.api.attributes.VariantAttr 'debug' but wasn't required.
>   - Required com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.AndroidTypeAttr 'Aar' and
>     found compatible value 'Aar'.
>   - Required org.gradle.usage 'java-api' and found compatible value 'java-api'.

Comment: Using Google Services 3.2.1 fixes this.

Comment: yeh - this seems to be a bug with com.google.gms:google-services:3.3.0. Downgrading to 3.2.1 resolved for me

Comment: Google Service is upgraded to 4.0.0 now. See https://developers.google.com/android/guides/google-services-plugin#introduction

Answer (score 85):

The `google-services` gradle plugin is made to work with Google Play Services and Firebase `15+`, but you're using it with version `12.0.1`.

The solution is to either:

- Upgrade your Play Services and Firebase dependencies to version `15+` [(note that they have different versions now)](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2018/05/announcing-new-sdk-versioning.html)
- Cancel your `google-services` upgrade to `3.3.0` until you upgrade to
  `15+`, that is, downgrading the gradle plugin to version `3.2.1`.

**EDIT 1**: There's [a known issue about using `google-services` `3.3` in multimodule apps](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/79235243). That means downgrading to `google-services` to `3.2.1` may be your only option until a new version that fixes the bug is released.

**EDIT 2**: The bug mentioned above has been fixed in the version `4.0.1` of the `google-services` gradle  plugin! (and the version `4.0.2` also fixes an NPE that occurred in some cases)

**BTW, you should move to FCM.**
[GCM will stop working in a not too distant future.](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2018/04/time-to-upgrade-from-gcm-to-fcm.html)

Comment: How do I have integrate on Ionic 3? Thanks!

Comment: @wilfredonoyola This works with gradle. If you use gradle with your Ionic project, then, it works exactly the same. Otherwise, it's just not related at all.

Comment: Yes, ionic 3 is related with gradle. Currently, I am having many bug when I make a new build on Android.

Comment: @wilfredonoyola Then, just post your own question if my answer and your searches are not enough to solve your build issues

Answer (score 27):

I got this error when I use google-services:3.3.0.

Downgrade to `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.1'` in your project .gradle.

It should solve the issue.

*Update: It should probably not occur in the current versions.*

Comment: I ran into this as well after updating to 3.3.0 but we *cannot downgrade* because this is needed for new play-services / firebase versions >= 15. See https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2018/05/announcing-new-sdk-versioning.html

Comment: @hardysim you should be able to use firebase version >= 15 with 3.2.1

Answer (score 7):

Faced with similar issue while upgrading to 3.3.1

Fixed it by downgrading to 3.2.1

We can use firebase version >=15 with 3.2.1

Answer (score 1):

Below steps worked for me ---

1. Go to the android/build.gradle file.
2. Search for `jcentre()` method.
3. Shift all the `jcenter()` methods to the bottom inside its block.

Comment: Worked for me as well. Unbelievable 

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar issue in past few days with.

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:15.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:15.0.0'
```

solution was to either downgrade to

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:12.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:12.0.1'
```

or consider leaving Google Cloud Services and upgrading to FCM entirely

Note that they have different version numbers you can look it up [here](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android#latest_sdk_versions)