# android gradle - google services plugin 3.3.0 error of " For input string: " 12" - how to solve?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

i recently updated google services to 3.3.0:

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.3.0'
```

Now i have the following  error and the recommendation from [google here](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2018/05/announcing-new-sdk-versioning.html) is to upgrade to 3.3.0 for the new firebase versioning.

here is the error:

[image]

As you can see its failing during the configuration phase.

if i look at the build error details i see the following :

```
org.gradle.api.ProjectConfigurationException: A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.addConfigurationFailure(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:94)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.notifyAfterEvaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:89)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.doConfigure(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:70)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.access$100(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:34)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator$ConfigureProject.run(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:110)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.evaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:50)
```

here are the details of my project gradle file:

```
   buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
        mavenCentral()
        google()
    }
    //kotlin version
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.2.41'
    ext.kotlin_ktx_version = '0.3'

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.3.0'
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.25.3'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}


allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()

        maven { url "http://dl.bintray.com/pt-midtrans/maven" }

        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }

        google()
    }



    project.ext {

        minimumSdkVersion = 16

        supportlib_version = '27.1.1'

        room_version = '1.0.0'

        espresso_version = '3.0.1'

        archLifecycleVersion = '1.1.1'

        dagger = '2.15'
    }

}

subprojects {
    //todo change this to loop once
    project.configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { details ->
            if (details.requested.group == 'com.android.support'
                    && !details.requested.name.contains('multidex')) {
                details.useVersion "$supportlib_version" //force all versions of support library to be the same. i tried commending out this entire block but that is not the issue
            }
    }
}


task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

and the app gradle file:

```
    buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
        google()
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    //buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion project.ext.minimumSdkVersion
        //check top level build.gradle  file for attributes -
        targetSdkVersion 27
        applicationId "com.mobile.mypackage"
        versionCode 1
        versionName "3" //whatever


        testInstrumentationRunner "com.mobile.mypackage.base.MyTestRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    flavorDimensions 'tier'

    buildTypes {
        release {
            debuggable false //for troubleshooting, should set to false in production build
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro', 'proguard-fresco.pro', 'proguard-gson.pro', 'proguard-midtrans.pro'
        }

        debugMini {
            //this is a proguarded version of debug build, turn off - InstaRun to use
            initWith debug
            minifyEnabled true
            useProguard true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro', 'proguard-fresco.pro', 'proguard-gson.pro', 'proguard-midtrans.pro'
            matchingFallbacks = ['debug']
        }
    }

    dexOptions {
        //for out of memory gc overhead error
        javaMaxHeapSize "6g"
    }
    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }

    androidExtensions {
        experimental = true
    }
    testOptions {
        //this seems to be absolutely nothing in build tools 25.0.3. after upgrading gradle will check again
        animationsDisabled = true
        execution 'ANDROID_TEST_ORCHESTRATOR'
    }

    productFlavors {

        def STRING = "String"
        def BOOLEAN = "boolean"
        def TRUE = "true"
        def FALSE = "false"
        def BASE_ENDPOINT = "BASE_ENDPOINT"


        staging {
            dimension 'tier'
      buildConfigField STRING, BASE_ENDPOINT, '"https://api.myendpoint.com"'
      versionNameSuffix '-STAGING'
            applicationIdSuffix 'staging'
        }

        labs {
            dimension 'tier'
            ext.alwaysUpdateBuildId = false

              buildConfigField STRING, BASE_ENDPOINT, '"https://api.myendpoint.com"'
              versionNameSuffix '-LABs'
            applicationIdSuffix 'labs'
        }

        prod {
            dimension 'tier'
            buildConfigField STRING, BASE_ENDPOINT, '"https://api.myendpoint.com"'
          }
    }
}

kapt {
    useBuildCache = false //toggle this to see if it will help
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    implementation("com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$supportlib_version") {
        force = true
    }
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'

    implementation "com.android.support:support-annotations:$supportlib_version"
    implementation("com.android.support:design:$supportlib_version") {
        force = true
    }

    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'

    //firebase

    implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-core:15.0.2") {
        force = true
    }
    implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:15.1.0") {
        force = true
    }
    implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-config:15.0.2") {
        force = true
    }
    implementation("com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:15.0.0") {
        force = true
    }
    implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:15.0.2") {
        force = true
    }

    //rxjava
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.1.6'
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.1'
    implementation 'com.jakewharton.rxbinding2:rxbinding:2.0.0'

    //square
    //testAnnotationProcessor "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:$dagger"
    implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger:$dagger"
    //annotationProcessor "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:$dagger"
    kapt "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:$dagger"
    implementation 'com.github.ajalt:timberkt:1.3.0'
    implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.8.1'
   // annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.8.1'
    kapt 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.8.1'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.9.1'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2:2.3.0'
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0"
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0"
    androidTestImplementation 'com.squareup.rx.idler:rx2-idler:0.9.0' //for espresso

    implementation 'com.hannesdorfmann.mosby:viewstate:2.0.1'

    //------Architecture Components ------------

    //room db
    implementation "android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:$room_version"
    //annotationProcessor "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:$room_version"
    implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:common-java8:1.1.1"
    kapt "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:$room_version"
    implementation "android.arch.persistence.room:rxjava2:$room_version"

    // Lifecycles only (no ViewModel or LiveData)
    implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:runtime:$archLifecycleVersion"
    //annotationProcessor "android.arch.lifecycle:compiler:$archLifecycleVersion"
    kapt "android.arch.lifecycle:compiler:$archLifecycleVersion"
    implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:$archLifecycleVersion"

    //------END Architecture Components ------------

    //event Bus
    implementation 'org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.0.0'

    //FB
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.32.0'
    //implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-applinks:[4,5)'
    implementation 'com.facebook.fresco:fresco:1.3.0'
    implementation 'com.facebook.stetho:stetho:1.5.0'
    implementation 'com.facebook.stetho:stetho-okhttp3:1.5.0'

    //testing
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.uiautomator:uiautomator-v18:2.1.3'
    testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-core:2.15.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-android:2.8.9'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.github.fabioCollini:DaggerMock:0.8.4'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:mockwebserver:3.8.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'


    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:rules:1.0.2'

    // Espresso dependencies
    androidTestImplementation "com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:$espresso_version"
    androidTestImplementation "com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:$espresso_version"
    androidTestImplementation "com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-intents:$espresso_version"
    // androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-accessibility:3.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation "com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-web:$espresso_version"
    androidTestImplementation "com.android.support.test.espresso.idling:idling-concurrent:$espresso_version"
    androidTestImplementation "com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-idling-resource:$espresso_version"

    //UI dependencies
    implementation 'com.andreabaccega:android-edittext-validator:1.3.4'
    implementation 'uk.co.chrisjenx:calligraphy:2.3.0'
    implementation "com.imgix:imgix-java:1.1.10"
    implementation 'com.github.markomilos:paginate:0.5.1'
    implementation 'com.sprylab.android.texturevideoview:texturevideoview:1.2.1'
    implementation 'com.balysv:material-ripple:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.github.d-max:spots-dialog:0.7@aar' //loading screen
    implementation 'com.jaredrummler:material-spinner:1.1.0'//drop down list
    implementation 'com.github.ganfra:material-spinner:1.1.1'//drop down list
    implementation 'com.bartoszlipinski:recyclerviewheader2:2.0.1'
    //implementation 'com.github.takusemba:multisnaprecyclerview:1.1.1' //snap
    implementation 'com.crystal:crystalrangeseekbar:1.1.1'
    implementation 'com.github.faruktoptas:FancyShowCaseView:1.0.0'

    //data structures
    implementation 'com.scalified:tree:0.2.4'

    //parcelable
    implementation 'org.parceler:parceler-api:1.1.9'
    //annotationProcessor 'org.parceler:parceler:1.1.9'
    kapt 'org.parceler:parceler:1.1.9'
    //payment gateways
    //implementation 'co.omise:omise-android:2.3.+'
    implementation 'co.omise:omise-android:2.6.4'
    implementation 'com.braintreepayments.api:braintree:1.+'
    debugImplementation 'com.midtrans:uikit:1.17.0-SANDBOX'
    debugMiniImplementation 'com.midtrans:uikit:1.17.0-SANDBOX'
    releaseImplementation 'com.midtrans:uikit:1.17.0'

    //fresh chat
    implementation 'com.github.freshdesk:freshchat-android:1.3.1'

    implementation'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.2'

        //one signal
        implementation 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:[3.7.1, 3.99.99]'

        //retrofit pretty logs
        implementation('com.github.ihsanbal:LoggingInterceptor:2.0.2') {
            exclude group: 'org.json', module: 'json'
        }

        //barcode scanner
        implementation 'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.5.0'

        //masking text
        implementation 'com.redmadrobot:inputmask:2.3.0'

        // Analytics
        implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:15.0.2"
        implementation 'com.appsflyer:af-android-sdk:4+@aar'
        implementation 'com.android.installreferrer:installreferrer:1.0'

        //runtime permissions
        implementation 'com.karumi:dexter:4.2.0'

        //chrome custom tabs
        implementation 'saschpe.android:customtabs:1.0.9'

        //searching - https://github.com/algolia/algoliasearch-client-android/releases
        implementation 'com.algolia:algoliasearch-android:3.21.11'

        //credit card scanner
        implementation 'io.card:android-sdk:5.5.1'

        //firebase test orchestrator
        androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
        androidTestUtil 'com.android.support.test:orchestrator:1.0.2'

        //kotlin
        implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version"
        implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:$kotlin_version"

        //kotlin ktx
        implementation "androidx.core:core-ktx:$kotlin_ktx_version"

    }

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services' //add to bottom of file
```

if i downgrade to 3.2.1 i get the following build error:

```
5 [ERROR] [com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.DesugarTransform] Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(Preconditions.java:108)
at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.DefaultMethodClassFixer$DefaultMethodFinder.visit(DefaultMethodClassFixer.java:483)
at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:621)
at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:500)
at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.DefaultMethodClassFixer.defaultMethodsDefined(DefaultMethodClassFixer.java:331)
at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.DefaultMethodClassFixer.visitEnd(DefaultMethodClassFixer.java:91)
at org.objectweb.asm.ClassVisitor.visitEnd(ClassVisitor.java:339)
at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.InterfaceDesugaring.visitEnd(InterfaceDesugaring.java:112)
at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:702)
at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:500)
at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.Desugar.desugarClassesInInput(Desugar.java:477)
at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.Desugar.desugarOneInput(Desugar.java:361)
at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.Desugar.desugar(Desugar.java:314)
at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.Desugar.main(Desugar.java:711)
```

**UPDATE:**

AFTER downgrading to google services 3.2.1 i now face the following error while build the gradle project:

```
14:37:49.269 [ERROR] [com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.DesugarTransform] Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(Preconditions.java:108)
at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.DefaultMethodClassFixer$DefaultMethodFinder.visit(DefaultMethodClassFixer.java:483)
at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:621)
at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:500)
at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.DefaultMethodClassFixer.defaultMethodsDefined(DefaultMethodClassFixer.java:331)
at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.DefaultMethodClassFixer.visitEnd(DefaultMethodClassFixer.java:91)
at org.objectweb.asm.ClassVisitor.visitEnd(ClassVisitor.java:339)
at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.InterfaceDesugaring.visitEnd(InterfaceDesugaring.java:112)
at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:702)
at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:500)
at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.Desugar.desugarClassesInInput(Desugar.java:477)
at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.Desugar.desugarOneInput(Desugar.java:361)
at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.Desugar.desugar(Desugar.java:314)
at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.Desugar.main(Desugar.java:711)
```

UPDATE: It seems when disable oneSignal Sdk the deSugar error disappears on 3.2.0 .  so i speculate that this has to do something with firebase versioning.  but there is still an issue using 3.3.0. i will contact oneSignal seperately.

I have no idea how to fix this. i am using 4.6 and also tried 4.4 of gradle wrapper (just in case).

Comment: what about `:google-services:3.2.0'`?

Comment: looks like the same problem as in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50132601/gradle-more-than-one-variant-of-project-mylib-matches-the-consumer-attributes

Comment: no its not the same in my opinion @Hardysim. i already versioned firebase. after versioning firebase with version 3.3.0 i get For input string: " 12" in the configuration phase of gradle.  but if i downgrade as recommended i get a desugar transform error.

Comment: i see a bug report here:  https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/79230924

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/50540761

Answer (score 2):

use classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.0'

Comment: i updated my question. i tried 3.2.0 but i get a desugar error . see the update.  i also tried 3.2.1 wtih same results. any ideas ?

Comment: we need 3.3.0 for new play-services / firebase versions. see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50132601/gradle-more-than-one-variant-of-project-mylib-matches-the-consumer-attributes/50166526#comment87357423_50166526

Comment: im upvoting this as a temporary solution as it works if you use 3.2.1 i was successfully able to build out including firebase versioning.