# React-Native: Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'

Tags: react-native, gradle

I am kind of new to the react-native thing so please excuse me for maybe making stupid mistakes.

I basically tried everything I could find before posting here and by now am not sure if this is something on my end (aka me being stupid) or a bug due to recent updates somewhere.

So, my problem is the error message mentioned above which I am getting when trying to build the app (either by using `react-native run-android` or even with `gradlew clean`). I post the full error message below as well as my app/build.gradle, build.gradle and settings.gradle files.

I left all the files the way they were created by "react-native init" and "just" added the commands I had to add according to the respective libraries' installation guides.

Due to recent changes in the Firebase SDKs I had to change quite a bit when it comes to gradle version, etc. which is why I wonder if this issue has anything to do with that?!

Oh, and the version numbers:

```
"dependencies": {
"babel-core": "^6.26.3",
"eslint": "^4.19.1",
"fbjs": "^0.8.16",
"react": "16.3.1",
"react-native": "0.55.4",
"react-native-firebase": "^4.1.0",
"react-native-navigation": "^1.1.458",
"react-native-vector-icons": "^4.6.0",
"react-redux": "^5.0.7",
"redux": "^4.0.0",
"redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
"redux-thunk": "^2.2.0"
}
```

I installed every package with yarn (`yarn add react-native-vector-icons`, etc.) and npm (`npm install`, as well as `npm install react-native-vector-icons`, etc.) to make sure it's not related to any of those. In between I removed the whole node_modules folder of course.
Neither did `react-native link` help.

It's also not limited to the mentioned `react-native-vector-icons` package: I removed it from my project completely and the same error just pops up for another package.

I appreciate any help and hints!

Thank you very much in advance!

Dustin

ERROR MESSAGE:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

    * What went wrong:
    A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
    > Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
       > More than one variant of project :react-native-vector-icons matches the consumer attributes:
           - Configuration ':react-native-vector-icons:debugApiElements' variant android-aidl:
               - Found artifactType 'android-aidl' but wasn't required.
               - Required com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr 'debug' and found compatible value 'debug'.
               - Found com.android.build.api.attributes.VariantAttr 'debug' but wasn't required.
               - Required com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.AndroidTypeAttr 'Aar' and found compatible value 'Aar'.
               - Required org.gradle.usage 'java-api' and found compatible value 'java-api'.
           - Configuration ':react-native-vector-icons:debugApiElements' variant android-classes:
               - Found artifactType 'android-classes' but wasn't required.
               - Required com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr 'debug' and found compatible value 'debug'.
               - Found com.android.build.api.attributes.VariantAttr 'debug' but wasn't required.
               - Required com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.AndroidTypeAttr 'Aar' and found compatible value 'Aar'.
               - Required org.gradle.usage 'java-api' and found compatible value 'java-api'.
           - Configuration ':react-native-vector-icons:debugApiElements' variant android-manifest:
               - Found artifactType 'android-manifest' but wasn't required.
               - Required com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr 'debug' and found compatible value 'debug'.
               - Found com.android.build.api.attributes.VariantAttr 'debug' but wasn't required.
               - Required com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.AndroidTypeAttr 'Aar' and found compatible value 'Aar'.
               - Required org.gradle.usage 'java-api' and found compatible value 'java-api'.
           - Configuration ':react-native-vector-icons:debugApiElements' variant android-renderscript:
               - Found artifactType 'android-renderscript' but wasn't required.
               - Required com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr 'debug' and found compatible value 'debug'.
               - Found com.android.build.api.attributes.VariantAttr 'debug' but wasn't required.
               - Required com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.AndroidTypeAttr 'Aar' and found compatible value 'Aar'.
               - Required org.gradle.usage 'java-api' and found compatible value 'java-api'.
           - Configuration ':react-native-vector-icons:debugApiElements' variant jar:
               - Found artifactType 'jar' but wasn't required.
               - Required com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr 'debug' and found compatible value 'debug'.
               - Found com.android.build.api.attributes.VariantAttr 'debug' but wasn't required.
               - Required com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.AndroidTypeAttr 'Aar' and found compatible value 'Aar'.
               - Required org.gradle.usage 'java-api' and found compatible value 'java-api'.
```

APP/BUILD.GRADLE:

```
apply plugin: "com.android.application"

import com.android.build.OutputFile

/**
 * The react.gradle file registers a task for each build variant (e.g. bundleDebugJsAndAssets
 * and bundleReleaseJsAndAssets).
 * These basically call `react-native bundle` with the correct arguments during the Android build
 * cycle. By default, bundleDebugJsAndAssets is skipped, as in debug/dev mode we prefer to load the
 * bundle directly from the development server. Below you can see all the possible configurations
 * and their defaults. If you decide to add a configuration block, make sure to add it before the
 * `apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"` line.
 *
 * project.ext.react = [
 *   // the name of the generated asset file containing your JS bundle
 *   bundleAssetName: "index.android.bundle",
 *
 *   // the entry file for bundle generation
 *   entryFile: "index.android.js",
 *
 *   // whether to bundle JS and assets in debug mode
 *   bundleInDebug: false,
 *
 *   // whether to bundle JS and assets in release mode
 *   bundleInRelease: true,
 *
 *   // whether to bundle JS and assets in another build variant (if configured).
 *   // See http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Build-Variants
 *   // The configuration property can be in the following formats
 *   //         'bundleIn${productFlavor}${buildType}'
 *   //         'bundleIn${buildType}'
 *   // bundleInFreeDebug: true,
 *   // bundleInPaidRelease: true,
 *   // bundleInBeta: true,
 *
 *   // whether to disable dev mode in custom build variants (by default only disabled in release)
 *   // for example: to disable dev mode in the staging build type (if configured)
 *   devDisabledInStaging: true,
 *   // The configuration property can be in the following formats
 *   //         'devDisabledIn${productFlavor}${buildType}'
 *   //         'devDisabledIn${buildType}'
 *
 *   // the root of your project, i.e. where "package.json" lives
 *   root: "../../",
 *
 *   // where to put the JS bundle asset in debug mode
 *   jsBundleDirDebug: "$buildDir/intermediates/assets/debug",
 *
 *   // where to put the JS bundle asset in release mode
 *   jsBundleDirRelease: "$buildDir/intermediates/assets/release",
 *
 *   // where to put drawable resources / React Native assets, e.g. the ones you use via
 *   // require('./image.png')), in debug mode
 *   resourcesDirDebug: "$buildDir/intermediates/res/merged/debug",
 *
 *   // where to put drawable resources / React Native assets, e.g. the ones you use via
 *   // require('./image.png')), in release mode
 *   resourcesDirRelease: "$buildDir/intermediates/res/merged/release",
 *
 *   // by default the gradle tasks are skipped if none of the JS files or assets change; this means
 *   // that we don't look at files in android/ or ios/ to determine whether the tasks are up to
 *   // date; if you have any other folders that you want to ignore for performance reasons (gradle
 *   // indexes the entire tree), add them here. Alternatively, if you have JS files in android/
 *   // for example, you might want to remove it from here.
 *   inputExcludes: ["android/**", "ios/**"],
 *
 *   // override which node gets called and with what additional arguments
 *   nodeExecutableAndArgs: ["node"],
 *
 *   // supply additional arguments to the packager
 *   extraPackagerArgs: []
 * ]
 */

project.ext.react = [
    entryFile: "index.js"
]

apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"
apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/fonts.gradle"

/**
 * Set this to true to create two separate APKs instead of one:
 *   - An APK that only works on ARM devices
 *   - An APK that only works on x86 devices
 * The advantage is the size of the APK is reduced by about 4MB.
 * Upload all the APKs to the Play Store and people will download
 * the correct one based on the CPU architecture of their device.
 */
def enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture = false

/**
 * Run Proguard to shrink the Java bytecode in release builds.
 */
def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = false

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.seroleashed.budgetmanager"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
    }
    splits {
        abi {
            reset()
            enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
            universalApk false  // If true, also generate a universal APK
            include "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
        }
    }
    // applicationVariants are e.g. debug, release
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            // For each separate APK per architecture, set a unique version code as described here:
            // http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/apk-splits
            def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a":1, "x86":2]
            def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
            if (abi != null) {  // null for the universal-debug, universal-release variants
                output.versionCodeOverride =
                        versionCodes.get(abi) * 1048576 + defaultConfig.versionCode
            }
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile project(':react-native-vector-icons')
    compile project(':react-native-navigation')
    compile(project(':react-native-firebase')) {
        transitive = false
    }
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation project(':react-native-vector-icons')
    implementation project(':react-native-navigation')
    implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.1"
    implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
    implementation project(':react-native-firebase')
    // RNFirebase required dependencies
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:15.0.0"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:15.0.2"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:15.1.0"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-database:15.0.0"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:15.0.2"
}

// Run this once to be able to run the application with BUCK
// puts all compile dependencies into folder libs for BUCK to use
task copyDownloadableDepsToLibs(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.compile
    into 'libs'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

BUILD.GRADLE:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.3.0'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
        }

        google()
    }
}
```

SETTINGS.GRADLE:

```
rootProject.name = 'BudgetManager'
include ':app'
include ':react-native-vector-icons'
project(':react-native-vector-icons').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/android')
include ':react-native-navigation'
project(':react-native-navigation').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-navigation/android/app')
include ':react-native-firebase'
project(':react-native-firebase').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-firebase/android')
include ':react-native-vector-icons'
project(':react-native-vector-icons').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/android')
include ':react-native-navigation'
project(':react-native-navigation').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native
```

Answer (score 14):

Moving the `google()` to the top can sometimes solve issues like this. 
an example fix from your code

```
buildscript {
    google()
    repositories {
        jcenter()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.3.0'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenLocal()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
        }  
    }
}
```

Comment: I can only say strange but true

Comment: putting `google()` outside the `repositories{}` ?
For me it gives an error: 
`> Could not find method google() for arguments [] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.initialization.DefaultScriptHandler.`

Comment: This answer was from years ago, they may have changed how things work in Gradle. I would make sure you have `allprojects` with google() in the repositories with google() in the top level in `buildscript`

Answer (score 7):

You can run the following command at your project's root folder

```
1. You need to delete both ios,android and node module folder. Run the following commands
2. > npm install //to get the node module folder
3. > react-native upgrade //to get android and ios folder
4. > react-native link // for linking the libraries
5. > react-native run android/ios
```

Comment: Hey @Deva. Thank you very much for answering so quickly. Just to make sure we are talking about the same "root folder": you are talking about the root folder of the react-native project not the android project, right? Meaning the folder in which "app.json"-files, etc. are in?
Because if so I already tried that and it didn't work out as pointed out in my first post.

Comment: Thanks again for your help; I found the solution now (see answer below). I tried your suggestions before, too, and they didn't help in this specific case. But those work often very well so still huge thanks to you =)

Answer (score 5):

Why do I always find the answer to questions I have shortly after asking for it in a forum or on Stackoverflow? xD

Just found the solution in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50132601/gradle-more-than-one-variant-of-project-mylib-matches-the-consumer-attributes?rq=1):

Apparently there is a bug in the "google-services" version that I was using.
Downgrading from

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.3.0'
```

to

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.1'
```

in my "build.gradle" file made the deal.

Comment: This helped the issue that I was facing. I was thinking all the while that the issue is Variants and Flavor dimension. The moment I changed it to 3.2.1, things started to work. Thanks for posting this.

Answer (score 2):

I began as @Prahbu but changed in the middle so I thought I'd post what I did as a different answer :

here is what I did (in the project's root folder as well) :

```
1. You need to delete both ios,android and node module folder. Afterwards, you can run the following commands
2. > npm install //to get the node module folder
3. > react-native-git-upgrade
```

You'll eventually stumble upon [this error](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/21241). In this case, delete your `.babelrc` (after you saved its content), you may for example rename it to .babelrc2, and replace the generated `.babelrc` with yours when you're done.

If the react-native-git-upgrade didn't generate the ios and android folder, run

```
react-native eject
```

And all that is left is, as per the original answer,

```
4. > react-native link // for linking the libraries
5. > react-native run android/ios
```

Answer (score 1):

run `cd android && ./gradlew clean`

Answer (score 0):

I just had this issue. For me, the fix was simply running the run command again.

```
react-native run-android
```