# Module for AAR is not working for gitlab CI

Tags: android, gradle, gitlab, continuous-integration, aar

I have a multi module project and I needed to create a module for my aar.

Here's is the gradle file:

```
configurations.maybeCreate("default")
artifacts.add("default", file('my-aar-1.0.0.aar'))
```

And there's another module that implement this artifact.
When I run `./gradlew build` directly from android studio works normally but in my CI script I'm facing this error:

```
Install Android SDK Platform-Tools (revision: 34.0.5) finished.
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':features:app:buildProdBetaPreBundle'.
> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration 
':features:app:prodBetaRuntimeClasspath'.
> Could not resolve project :myaar.
 Required by:
     project :app > project :module:secondmodule
  > No matching configuration of project :myaar was found. The consumer was configured to find a runtime of a component, preferably optimized for Android, as well as attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr' with value 'beta', attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.ProductFlavor:default' with value 'prod', attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.AgpVersionAttr' with value '7.4.2', attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'androidJvm' but:
      - Configuration 'ktlintRuleset':
          - Other compatible attributes:
              - Doesn't say anything about com.android.build.api.attributes.AgpVersionAttr (required '7.4.2')
              - Doesn't say anything about com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr (required 'beta')
              - Doesn't say anything about com.android.build.api.attributes.ProductFlavor:default (required 'prod')
              - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for Android)
              - Doesn't say anything about its usage (required a runtime)
              - Doesn't say anything about org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type (required 'androidJvm')
```

Its something that I need to put in the gradle file from aar module or its is my script?

```
image: public.ecr.aws/openjdk:11jdk-new

variables:
  ANDROID_COMPILE_SDK: "28"
  ANDROID_BUILD_TOOLS: "28.0.2"
  ANDROID_SDK_TOOLS:   "4333796"
  ENVIRONMENT: $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME
  REGION: $AWS_DEFAULT_REGION

stages:
 - build

lintDebug:
 image: public.ecr.aws/android:latest
 stage: build
 artifacts:
 name: "$CI_JOB_NAME-$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME"
 when: always
 paths:
  - ./builds/poc-pipeline-android/app/build/outputs/*
 before_script:
- |
  yes | sdkmanager --licenses && \
  yes | sdkmanager --update --channel=0 && \
  yes | sdkmanager \
  "platforms;android-30" \
  "platforms;android-29" \
  "platforms;android-28" \
  "platforms;android-27" \
  "platforms;android-26" \
  "platforms;android-25" \
  "platforms;android-24" \
  "platforms;android-23" \
  "platforms;android-22" \
  "build-tools;30.0.3" \
  "build-tools;30.0.2" \
  "build-tools;30.0.0" \
  "build-tools;29.0.3" \
  "build-tools;29.0.2" \
  "build-tools;29.0.1" \
  "build-tools;29.0.0" \
  "build-tools;28.0.3" \
  "build-tools;28.0.2" \
  "build-tools;28.0.1" \
  "build-tools;28.0.0" \
  "build-tools;27.0.3" \
  "build-tools;27.0.2" \
  "build-tools;27.0.1" \
  "build-tools;27.0.0" \
  "build-tools;26.0.2" \
  "build-tools;26.0.1" \
  "build-tools;25.0.3" \
  "build-tools;24.0.3" \
  "build-tools;23.0.3" \
  "build-tools;22.0.1" \
  "build-tools;21.1.2" \
  "build-tools;19.1.0" \
  "build-tools;17.0.0" \
  "system-images;android-30;google_apis;x86" \
  "system-images;android-29;google_apis;x86" \
  "system-images;android-28;google_apis;x86_64" \
  "system-images;android-26;google_apis;x86" \
  "system-images;android-25;google_apis;armeabi-v7a" \
  "system-images;android-24;default;armeabi-v7a" \
  "system-images;android-22;default;armeabi-v7a" \
  "extras;android;m2repository" \
  "extras;google;m2repository" \
  "extras;google;google_play_services" \
  "extras;m2repository;com;android;support;constraint;constraint-layout;1.0.2" \
  "extras;m2repository;com;android;support;constraint;constraint-layout;1.0.1" \
  "add-ons;addon-google_apis-google-23" \
  "add-ons;addon-google_apis-google-22" \
  "add-ons;addon-google_apis-google-21"
 script:
- ./gradlew build
```

Comment: Would one of [those answers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50348927/6309) help?

Comment: @VonC unfortunally no