# Google services 3.3.0 upgrade error - more than one variant of project matches

Tags: java, android, gradle, google-play-services-3.3.0

I updated my google services from 3.2.1 to 3.3.0 and started receiving following error

**Implementation**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2'
        classpath "com.google.gms:google-services:3.3.0" // <- Update
    }
}
```

**Error**

```
More than one variant of project :asq-react-native-facebook-log-in matches the consumer attributes:
  - Configuration ':asq-react-native-facebook-log-in:debugApiElements' variant android-aidl:
      - Found artifactType 'android-aidl' but wasn't required.
      - Required com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr 'debug' and found compatible value 'debug'.
      - Found com.android.build.api.attributes.VariantAttr 'debug' but wasn't required.
      - Required com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.AndroidTypeAttr 'Aar' and found compatible value 'Aar'.
      - Required default 'development' but no value provided.
      - Required org.gradle.usage 'java-api' and found compatible value 'java-api'.
```

This error is happening in my main project, however error itself is referring to this project https://github.com/Asimetriq/asq-react-native-facebook-log-in/tree/master/android (this is one of the dependencies in my main project)

The `- Configuration` bit of the error is repeated several times (same content, didn't include it here to keep things cleaner.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50171620/2003986), there is a [known bug](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/79235243) with `Google services 3.3.0`

Either use the `4.0.1` version which fixes the bug or downgrade to `3.2.1`